# ASP.NET - How to remove dynamically added Gridviews from Asp:Panel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, panel

I am populating an Asp:Panel with gridviews generated dynamically based on user selection. As the user changes the selection criteria and the date, the panel to show the new gridviews based on the search criteria. I am doing MyPanel.Controls.Clear(), but the gridviews are still showing the old result. Then i tried the following, but still of no use, the panle is always showing the first result.

```
            foreach (Control c in MyPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (c is GridView)
                {
                    MyPanel.Controls.Remove(c);
                    //Response.Write("**"+c.ID);
                }
               // else
                   // Response.Write("##" + c.ID);

            }
            Response.Write("cnt=" + MyPanel.Controls.Count ); // Always showing as 1 even when the count is greater than 1.
```

Any idea how i can clean the panel each time before i try to populate the panel with new results as gridviews?

ray..

Answer (score -1):

Why you are generating panel each time make one or two panel as you required and just change their content or set visible hide true or false as you required creating panel each time is not a good approach.

Comment: I am not generating the asp:panel at runtime, i am just adding controls to the static panel at run time. The panel is populated based on the search results of the user input. So when the result change, on button click i am trying to clear all the controls in the panel before  filling with new ones. The controls i am adding are only gridviews.

Comment: you are doing this in wrong way there is no need to declare panel at run time.

Comment: I am NOT declaring panel at runtime. Panel is defined in the aspx page. I am only adding controls like gridview to the panel from code behind dynamically.

Comment: Are you talking about binding gridview or adding control ?